# Add +1 to clicked element in array React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I got a page with some blog posts and I want users to have the ability to like/thumbs up each post and see how many likes each post has.

Right now when I like one post, all the posts get the same amount of likes. How do I only like the post I'm clicking?

Here's relevant parts of my code:

```
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    let [thumbsNumber, setThumbsNumber] = useState(0)

    const thumbsUp = (x) => {
        console.log('Clicked thumb: ', x)
        setThumbsNumber((thumbsNumber += 1))
    }


return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post, index) => (
                <div key={index} style={{ marginBottom: '10px' }}>
                
                                <p style={{ float: 'right' }}>{thumbsNumber}</p>
                                <ThumbUpAltIcon
                                    className="thumbsUpBtn"
                                    onClick={() => thumbsUp(post.id)}
                                ></ThumbUpAltIcon>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `thumbsNumber` should be an object, and when setting the number, you should add/update the key (`id`) of the post.

**Note**: I'm using `?? 0` to substitute 0 if `thumbsNumber[id]` is not defined.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
const [thumbsNumber, setThumbsNumber] = useState({})

const thumbsUp = (id) => {
  console.log('Clicked thumb: ', id)
  setThumbsNumber(thumbs => ({
    ...thumbs,
    [id]: (thumbs[id] ?? 0) + 1
  }))
}


return (
  <div>
    {posts.map((post, index) => (
    <div key={index} style={{ marginBottom: '10px' }}>
      <p style={{ float: 'right' }}>{thumbsNumber[post.id] ?? 0}</p>
      <ThumbUpAltIcon className="thumbsUpBtn" onClick={()=> thumbsUp(post.id)} >
      </ThumbUpAltIcon>
    </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add like's number to each post for example

```
{
  id: 2,
  title: "name",
  ...,
  likes: 1,
}
```

and after that you must increase the likes number

```
setPosts([...posts, {this field object with new likes number}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep inside each post, its number of likes.
for example this is post:

```
{id: 1 ,name: 'post1', data: 'this is post' , numberOfLikes: 0}
```

then update the number of likes by the id of the post.